# Python - Search for a specific time range in text file (sed -n equivalent)

Tags: python, sed

I'm trying to make a python script that outputs a specific time range from a log file (similar to the sed command listed below):

```
sed -n '/2017-01-26 18:00/ , /2017-01-26 18:02/p' /logfile.log
```

```
2017-01-26 18:00:00
2017-01-26 18:01:01
2017-01-26 18:01:02
2017-01-26 18:01:09
2017-01-26 18:01:09
2017-01-26 18:01:11
2017-01-26 18:02:01
```

My python script is searching for a fixed string and not like the sed command above (I suspect that I am doing something wrong, but I can't find the error - please check the code below):

Please point me where the code should be changed and also advises for code enhancement. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime, time, os, sys, re
from datetime import timedelta
counter = 0
avgtime = 0

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
pasttime = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

timestamp = now.strftime("%y%m%d")
fiveago   = now - timedelta(minutes=5,seconds=now.second)
current   = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
pasttime  = fiveago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
pattern   = str(current + "|" + pasttime)

f = open('/logs/' + sys.argv[1] + '/' + 'u_ex' + timestamp + '.log', 'r')
for line in f:
        if "POST" in line:
                if re.search(pattern, line, re.IGNORECASE):
                        date = line.split(' ')[1]
                        time = line.split(' ')[14]
                        avgtime += int(time)
                        counter += 1
                        print(date,time)
f.close()

print(pattern)
print("Total amount of time: ",counter)
print("Total scan time: ",avgtime)
print("Average scan time: ",avgtime / counter)
```

Comment: Sed command is actually this:

sed -n '/2017-01-26 18:00/ , /2017-01-26 18:02/p' /logfile.log

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? Your sed commands seems to only display lines within a time range, but your python code does compute some averages?

Comment: Yes, it gets the arithmetic mean for times taken in SQL transactions... But the issue that I am having now is to make the regex work in the same way as the sed command does

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems that you are not happy with the code you have written here, but you haven't explained what you need help with. [ask]

Comment: @HåkenLid he explained in the comments, I now got the question and working on a solution

Comment: @RodAssis still: you might make your question more explicit. Currently it's only in the title, it should also be at the end of the post

Comment: @hansaplast Sorry for not being clear on my question....

Basically, this sed command will output lines from 18:00 till 18:02 (including 18:01). It happens that using re.search function on my python script will only give me results matching 18:00 & 18:02 (it will exclude 18:01 and every time within that range).

I need something in Python like the sed command (it outputs 18:00, 18:01 & 18:02). I've also tried 2016-01-26 18:00 + 2016-01-26 19:00, and sed works perfectly.

The main goal of this script is to get all entries within a 5 minutes range from current time to (current - 5mins ago)

Comment: @RodAssis yes, that's true. I added an answer below to explain why you only find 18:00 and 18:02 and no times inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need the enteries from the log between time stamp that you pass.

```
import datetime, time, os, sys, re
from datetime import timedelta
counter = 0
avgtime = 0

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
pasttime = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=100000)

timestamp = now.strftime("%y%m%d")
fiveago   = now - timedelta(minutes=5,seconds=now.second)
current   = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
pasttime  = fiveago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
pattern   = str(current + "|" + pasttime)

print "Start time: ", pasttime ,"End time: ",current ,"\n\n"

filename ='/logs/' + sys.argv[1] + '/' + 'u_ex' + timestamp + '.log'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
for line in contents:
    if "POST" in line:
        date = line.split(' ')[1]
        time = line.split(' ')[14]
        logdatetime=date+" "+time

        if logdatetime <= current and logdatetime >= pasttime:
            print "yes, within the interval : " ,logdatetime
```

output

```
Start time:  2017-01-26 20:23 End time:  2017-01-26 20:28 


yes, within the interval :  2017-01-26 20:23:20
yes, within the interval :  2017-01-26 20:23:01
yes, within the interval :  2017-01-26 20:23:02
```

input used for this

```
POST 2017-01-26 20:23:20 XX
POST 2017-01-26 20:23:01 XC
POST 2017-01-26 20:23:02 CV
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:09 DAF
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:09 fASF
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:11 Sfas
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:01 fsAf
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:02 asf
POST 2017-01-26 20:20:03 asf
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what the problem is, but you are asking for sed equivalent of your command, so here is exact translation to python:

```
import sys, re
use = False
for line in open('/logfile.log'):
   if re.search('2017-01-26 18:00', line): use = True
   if use: sys.stdout.write(line)
   if re.search('2017-01-26 18:02', line): use = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that you only look for the two "edge times". In n your 3 minute timerange example this was `18:00` and `18:02`.

What the `sed` command does is:

```
sed -n '/2017-01-26 18:00/ , /2017-01-26 18:02/p' /logfile.log
```

1. iterate through the lines without printing (`-n`)
2. whenever sed finds `2017-01-26 18:00` it starts printing all lines
3. whenever sed finds `2017-01-26 18:02` it stops printing

In your example your regex pattern is:

```
2017-01-26 18:00|2017-01-26 18:02
```

And will only find *either* 18:00 *or* 18:02. So, what you can do is one of these:

1. parse the date out of the line and compare to a timerange, as in [Shijos  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882437/119861)
2. emulate sed, as in [theamks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882293/119861), but beware: this only works if both "edge timestamps" are present in the file
3. pimp your regex so it also searches for the times in between:

   ```
   pattern = "|".join([(now-timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for i in range(6)])
   ```

   this will produce e.g.:

   ```
   '2016-01-26 18:00|2016-01-26 17:59|2016-01-26 17:58|2016-01-26 17:57|2016-01-26 17:56|2016-01-26 17:55'
   ```